# Как правильно сделать профиль

Tags: php

У меня, в табличке пользователей, есть столбец `aboutme`, здесь мы записываем о себе! И, в меню пользователя, есть раздел "Профиль" Как сделать, чтоб изменения произошли у того пользователя, под которым зашел человек?

Comment: Вот мы записали о себе "Меня зовут Влад" Как чтоб это запись пошла в мой ак?

Comment: А чем пользователь идентифицируется в этой табличке?

Comment: Он запоминается в $_SESSION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_query('update `users` set `aboutme`="'.$aboutme.'" where `id`='.$_SESSION['user_id']);
```

Слово правильно здесь малоприменимо. Это ПРОСТЕЙШИЙ случай. Правильный займет около листа со всеми проверками.

Comment: АгА спсибо=)